# Loading pre-trained word vectors with fastrtext in R

Tags: r, word-embedding, fasttext

I'd like to use the pretrained word vectors by [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) in R. This should be possible with the 'fastrtext' library, but I'm having trouble loading the files.

How do I read the .vec file with R? 
How do I load the .bin file into R? 

For .bin files I've tried:

```
library(fastrtext)
model <- load_model(choose.files()) # load e.g. cc.frr.300.bin
Model file has wrong file format!
```

> Error in model$load(path) : Failure in fastrtext. Exit code: 1

Clearly, that's not the way to go. Any ideas?